# make the checkbox single choice

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I want to apply this code on vuejs
I replaced onclick by @click but it doesn't work!
ps: I'm beginner on vuejs

```
function onlyOne(checkbox) {
    var checkboxes = document.getElementsByName('check')
    checkboxes.forEach((item) => {
        if (item !== checkbox) item.checked = false
    })
}
<input type="checkbox" name="check" onclick="onlyOne(this)">
<input type="checkbox" name="check" onclick="onlyOne(this)">
<input type="checkbox" name="check" onclick="onlyOne(this)">
<input type="checkbox" name="check" onclick="onlyOne(this)">
```

Comment: When you need a single choice, usually you will need a Radio Button instead of a checkbox.

Comment: yes i now but i want use checkbox

Comment: I know that i'm not answering your question. But if you use a checkbox instead of a radio button, you will be providing wrong feedback to your users. Because the checkbox are usually to check several options, not only one. But when a user sees a radio button, they know they only can select one option.

Comment: sorry, but from the example code and the question wording it seems that your problem is more extensive than "why this particular code doesn`t work" - do you know how to use Vue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A basic approach to the question you stated:

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data() {
    return {
      checkboxes: [{
          checked: false
        },
        {
          checked: false
        },
        {
          checked: false
        },
        {
          checked: false
        },
      ]
    }
  },
  methods: {
    onChange(cb) {
      this.checkboxes = this.checkboxes.map(checkbox => ({ checked: cb == checkbox }))
    },
  },
  template: `
    <div>
      <div
        v-for="(checkbox, i) in checkboxes"
        :key="i"
      >
        <input
          type="checkbox"
          :checked="checkbox.checked"
          @change="() => onChange(checkbox)"
        />
        {{ checkbox.checked }}
      </div>
    </div>
  `
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app"></div>
```